# Flex desktop application: How to position elements relative to the window size

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, positioning

I am creating a desktop application with Flex for the first time. I am having problems with the position and size of the elements in the screen. For instance

- Elements with 100% width do not resize when the window is resized or maximized
- Elements positioned relative to the bottom of the window do not move when resizing or maximizing the window

How do I solve these problems? Are there any good practices that I should follow when using Flex to develop a desktop app?

Comment: By saying "Flex desktop application", I'm thinking of an AIR application.

Comment: Well, I did not want to restrict the question to AIR because I want it to work in both desktop and web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found what I needed in Adobe's official docs... I should have looked there in the first place:

[Laying Out Components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e4c.html)

One of my problems was that I was setting the width and height of the Application, and the Flash Player does not change that parameters even if you resize its window.

Answer (score 1):

from http://nondocs.blogspot.com/2007/04/flexfaqpercentwidthpercentheight.html :

> If you set percentWidth and
>   percentHeight of a UIComponent whose's
>   parent is not a Container these
>   properties may not effect the size of
>   the UIComponent. This is because
>   UIComponents do not actually check
>   percentWidth and percentHeight.
>   Instead the UIComponent's parent
>   Container checks it's childrens'
>   percentWidth and percentHeight and
>   resizes the children accordingly.